# Сохранение Cookie в Safari

Tags: javascript, cookie, iframe, safari, cross-domain

В safari есть проблема с куками тех сайтов которые пользователь не посещал.

То бишь, на странице google.com есть iframe yandex.com. И куки который поставил yandex.com не поставятся из-за политики safari которую я написал выше.

**Находил решения проблемы:**

- Сделать редирект на сайт который в iframe, и потом обратно на google.com - Этот метод сработал( Но сами понимаете это очень заметно и выглядит не совсем...)
- На google.com создать form, которая будет отправлять GET/POST запрос на yandex.com/cookies (допустим). При этом всем она будет работать для ifarme (посредством задавания атрибута target) - Такой способ не прокатил.

Вот у меня вопрос. Возможны ли еще какие-то решения данной проблемы?

Спасибо.